# Questions with poor English being closed rather than improved

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, english

When reviewing close votes, poor grammar is heavily voted down. The world is global and there are people from all over the world with all sorts of levels of English.

I didn't vote to close this: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/14064244

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766020/select-a-word-that-should-not-followed-by-xml-tag-using-regex

The question is perfectly valid (I've answered this question many times in the past). The only problem is it is written in broken English. The question was clear enough that even just the examples to be matched is enough information to write a correct answer.

The close vote system heavily favors people who click close without thinking and heavily disadvantages developers with poor English. This should be discouraged. When a tiny bit of rewriting fixes the grammar issues, we shouldn't be discouraging people who aren't fluent in English.

Comment: Any moderator can see that my close votes usually agree with the majority. I disagree with the close vote on this one so much that I came here to complain and will not be clicking "I understand."

Comment: The question is still too broad/unclear. Doesn't have to do with the poor english, but merely the lack of efforts shown by the OP.

Comment: I don't think the poor English is the issue there but the neglect of the guidance in the [tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) on what to include in a question.

Comment: The question isn't unclear because of the English, but because it's not clear what they're really trying to achieve, and/or why they think regex is the way to achieve it. If it was only spelling, punctuation and grammar it probably *would* have been edited for that rather than closed.

Comment: This looks like the classical misunderstanding of the "Unclear what you're asking" close reason. The fact that you think you know what the OP is looking for, does not mean the question is clear and on-topic. Also, _"I've answered this question many times in the past"_ might mean that you should've close-voted as duplicate.

Comment: I checked 10 of that user's questions. *None* of them contain anything resembling OP's own attempt, they all come down to "write some code for me". It has nothing to do with grammar, all are extremely low on effort.

Comment: The question is perfectly valid (I've answered this question many times in the past). So duplicates are valid?

Answer (score 11):

The question might not be unclear if you try very hard to understand the OP. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39766020/#comment66827767_39766020) probably provides the solution the OP is looking for. Still, it is off-topic: the OP just poses a problem and hasn't even shown what he/she tried. It doesn't matter that the question *might* be closed for the wrong reason: it needs to remain closed.

Answer (score 4):

True gems will likely be edited in shape irrespective of original quality, "plz give me teh codez" and other no-effort questions are likely to be downvoted even if grammar is perfect.

If you feel that you've found true unique question - edit, put bounty if needed... But if it is just work request with no value for future visitors - downvote seem to be good option.

For linked question:

"(I've answered this question many times in the past)" - this seem to be demonstration of effort OP put into the question and calls for downvotes due to lack of research/closing as duplicate.